# Adding auto vertical scroll to table body when adding rows dynamically

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/desytec/m69q2xwr/34/

```
<style>
.table-scroll tbody {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 250px;
}
</style>

<script>
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function() {
      var tableBody = $('#mytable tbody');
      var newRow =
         '<tr id="tr_' + count + '">' +
             '<td>Test Row ' + count + ' Col 1</td> ' +
             '<td>Test Row ' + count + ' Col 2</td>'
         '</tr>';
         tableBody.append(newRow);
         count++;
         if (count == 3)
             tableBody.addClass('table-scroll');
    });
    $('#btnDelete').on('click', function() {
      var tableBody = $('#mytable tbody');
         tableBody.children().last().remove();
         count--;
         if (count == 2)
             tableBody.removeClass('table-scroll');
    });
});
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="row ml-4">
        <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle m-4">Add row</button>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <button id="btnDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle m-4">Delete row</button>    
    </div>    
</div>

<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped dt-responsive w-100 table-bordered display nowrap table-hover mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to show a vertical scroll bar in a table body, leaving the header fixed when I add rows dynamically.

When I add a row and there are 3 rows added, I am adding a class to table body so that it should show the scroll bar but it did not work.

What is the right way to do that?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: `tableBody` is NOT the table... But the table body. That's why the CSS rule does not do anything... You are adding the `table-scroll` class to the wrong element. -- That would be `tableBody.closest("table").addClass('table-scroll');`... And the same for the class removal.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have change to this and still no scroll bar is shown: https://jsfiddle.net/desytec/m69q2xwr/48/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a little style tweak will get you there. I moved 'table-scroll' to be a class of the 'table' because I had to adjust the header row when the scrollbar appears. In the css I moved the `overflow-y` to `.table-scroll tbody` - and to keep your TD's from resizing as a consequence, add a rule for those to keep them at `50vw`. When the scrollbar appears the header and body mis-register. I added in a little shim on the header row to accommodate, and it's not perfect but it's darn close!

Also, rather than `count` to determine the scroll breakpoint, I measured the height of `tbody`.

```
.table-scroll {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 150px;
  display:block;
}

.table-scroll td {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnAdd').on('click', function() {
    var tableBody = $('#mytable tbody');
    let count = tableBody.children().length
    var newRow =
      '<tr id="tr_' + count + '">' +
      '<td>Test Row ' + count + ' Col 1</td> ' +
      '<td>Test Row ' + count + ' Col 2</td>'
    '</tr>';
    tableBody.append(newRow);
    adjustTable()
  });
  $('#btnDelete').on('click', function() {
    var tableBody = $('#mytable tbody');
    tableBody.children().last().remove();
    adjustTable()
  });
});

function adjustTable() {
  let maxHeight = 250
  // console.log($('#mytable tbody').height() > maxHeight)
  if ($('#mytable tbody').height() >= maxHeight) $('#mytable').addClass('table-scroll');
  else $('#mytable').removeClass('table-scroll');

}
```

```css
.table-scroll  {
  height: 285px;
}

.table-scroll tbody {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.table-scroll tbody td {
  width: 50vw;
}

#mytable .shim {
  display: none;
  width: 13px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #DFDFDF;
}

#mytable.table-scroll .shim {
  display: table-cell;
}

.table-container{
margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="row ml-4">
    <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle m-4">Add row</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <button id="btnDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle m-4">Delete row</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='table-container'>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped dt-responsive w-100 table-bordered display nowrap table-hover mb-0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th class='shim'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p>Other content...</p>
```

Comment: It worked, however, the column header got misaligned with respect to the table body. Is there a way to do that or should I to scroll the whole table?

Comment: @jstuardo  - updated my answer with a few tweaks. Please see description and code

Comment: Hello.... it worked, however, I had other problem. That table is inside a modal dialog. When the table-scroll class is added, the modal dialog height get reduced looking awful. So I decided to make the table header also part of the scroll and in order the modal dialog to not being resized, I tried to set the initial table height to 250 px, but I got other problem  with this approach. Since there is no row in the table, only the header, the header row is enlarged to fit the whole table height. This is for another question, I guess.

Comment: @jstuardo  - I updated my answer. just setting `.table-scroll  { height: 285px; }` seems to work. I also put a container around it but that isn't required